# How to override website audio files with inspector?

Tags: audio, google-chrome-devtools

So in chrome developer tools you can override css elements locally using local overrides. I am just wondering if this is possible with audio files as well. I have already done some background research but haven't found anything, so is it even possible or should I use an extension or a software for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible. When you set up your [Local Overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides) (LO), you specify a directory where DevTools should store the LO files. For example let's assume that you've set it to `~/Desktop/LO`. To override an audio file, just add it to your LO directory. The location of the audio file needs to match the exact location that is used on the web page. For example, suppose that this is how you access the audio file on your page:

```
<audio src="/audio/hello.mp3"></audio>
```

To override this file with LO, you should place the new audio file at `~/Desktop/LO/example.com/audio/hello.mp3`. The top level of the directory needs to match the domain of the audio file. In this case we're assuming that the full URL of the audio file is `https://example.com/audio/hello.mp3`.

Here's a video of the workflow: https://youtu.be/RRTKY262kHQ